# Android connection with other phone

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to create a simple social app. On this app, users can communicate via the internet. It will be a simple connection - notification sends from one to other users. (ex. user A sends a notification to user B. User B see a notification from user B).

How the best achieve this communication? Is Google Cloud Messaging is the best solution? How can I calculate costs?

Comment: Go for firebase cloud messaging. GCM is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the `Firebase` tools. With the details you provide, you will probably want to use a combination of `Firebase Realtime Database` + `Firebase Cloud Messaging` + `Firebase Cloud Functions`.

You choose a path on the `Realtime Database` to be the place where you write data. For instance, write messages to `users/:user_id/messages`. Then attach a trigger to this path with `Cloud Functions`, so every time something is written to this path you can fire a notification to the the other user with `Cloud Messaging`.

Reference:

[Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA5t7UBRDaARIsAOreQtgpDJs1qaEPVdUaARaxRqiEIkzKeirSHPGWdasdoB3DIHxa3FgKZJoaApnzEALw_wcB)

[Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/) .